# How to export Redux state field?

Tags: redux, redux-thunk

Got this error:

```
Property 'authnUser' does not exist on type 'TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState>'.
```

I try export like this:

```js
export const authnUser = (state: TypedUseSelectorHook<RootState>) =>
    state.authnUser
```

I have following declarations:

```js
interface RootState {
    authnResp: AuthnRes
    soldTickets: SoldTicketRes
}

const initialState: RootState = {
    authnResp: null,
    soldTickets: null,
}

const tikexAPI = createSlice({
    name: 'authnUser',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        setAuthnRes(state, action: PayloadAction<AuthnRes | null>) {
            state.authnResp = action.payload
        },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

It should probably be

```
export const authnUser = (state: RootState) =>
    state.authnUser
```